# GlassFish SSO, logout problem

Tags: java, glassfish, single-sign-on

I'm developing some J2EE applications that should have common login point. My apps are hosted on GlassFish v3 application server.

There is web.xml based security with FORM method (a HTML form with "j_security_check" action) and JDBC Realm on PostgreSQL 8.4 datasource. It worked absolutely fine while GlassFish SSO was disabled.

Now SSO is enabled on GF's HTTP Service page and it really works fine when I need to log in. Each my application lets a logged user in. But here is another problem.

My **logout** servlet now works properly only when I click "logout" twice.
After first "logout" click I stay logged in. Servlet code is below.

```
public class LogoutServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    //request.logout(); // tried this too
    request.getSession().invalidate(); // used to work properly
    response.sendRedirect("./"); // to welcome page
}
```

}

I would be pleased for some useful hints.

Thanks.

Comment: this reads very similar to a forum thread that I just found...  http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?messageID=224784.  I cannot conjure up a good answer based on what I am reading in the thread, but since you are closer to the topics being discussed, it may prove useful.